# IntelliSense parameter info not showing up

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm having some code like this:

```php
/**
* Some general description
*
* @param integer $var1 Description one
* @param integer $var2 Description two
* @param string $var3 Description three
* @param string $var4 Description four
*/

function askDumbQuestion($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4) { ... }
```

I actually want to see the parameter info, but IntelliSense doesn't show up (even if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>). For the default functions of php it just works fine.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Do you have the PHP extension installed?

Comment: **PHP IntelliSense** is intalled- should I install something else as well?